# How to handle @Prop() logic using getters/setters within StencilJS

Tags: stenciljs

I would like to add a getter / setter to my StencilJS component. As I'm currently aware, you cannot use the get / set logic with `@Prop()`. How would I generate similar logic in a StencilJS component?

For example, say I have the following **Angular** component, I could do the following:

```
  @Input()
  get enabled(): boolean {
    return this._enabledOverride == null ? this._getDefaultEnabled() : this.enabledOverride;
  }
  set enabled(value: boolean) {
    this._enabledOverride = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
  }

  _enabledOverride: boolean|null = null;

  private _getDefaultEnabled() {
    return this.stepControl ? this.stepControl.valid && this.interacted : this.interacted;
  }
```

My attempt at a StencilJS component would be the following:

**Child Component**

```
  _enabled: boolean;

  @Prop() enabled: boolean;

  @Watch('enabled')
  watchHandler(newValue: boolean, oldValue: boolean) {
    this._enabledOverride = coerceBooleanProperty(newValue);
    this._enabled = this._enabledOverride == null ? this.getDefaultEnabled() : this._enabledOverride;
  }

  _enabledOverride: boolean | null = null;
```

Here, I `Watch` for `enabled` to change, do logic, and set a **private** instance variable of `_enabled` to the updated value. This is great, for use within the instance. But what if I need to access the `enabled` property from the parent component, also my logic wouldn't run on page load since @Watch() isn't triggered on page load. Once it does run, there is now a mismatch in value between `enabled` and `_enabled`. So for example in my parent component if I had:

**Parent Component**

```
export class Parent {
  @Element() el: HTMLElement;

  componentWillLoad() {
    const childElements = this.el.querySelectorAll('app-child-component');
    childElements.forEach((el) => {
      // attempting to access the enabled property would be out of sync with the private _enabled
      console.log(el.enabled)
    })
  }
}
```

As seen above, attempting to access the enabled property would be out of sync with the private _enabled giving me an out-of-date property value. How should I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a method with the `@Method` decorator to act as a getter:

```js
@Method()
async getEnabled() {
  return this._enabledOverride == null ? this._getDefaultEnabled() : this.enabledOverride;
}
```

And then use it like

```js
const childElements = this.el.querySelectorAll('app-child-component');

await Promise.all(
  childElements.map(async el => console.log(await el.getEnabled()))
)
```